# Why is this JSON not being read correctly?

Tags: c#, json, unity-game-engine

I have a large list of names in JSON arranged by country and sorted into male and female. I would like to be able to access these names within unity to apply them to various generated game characters etc. When trying to do this I am receiving a Null reference error but am out of ideas on how to approach/ fix it.

I have tried creating a Dictionary to access the names. Here is an example of the JSON:

```
//json example

{
    "India":{
       "male":[
          "A_Jay",
          "Aaban",
          "Aabid",
          "Aabir",
          "Aadam"
        ],
       "female":[
          "A_Jay",
          "Aaban",
          "Aabid",
          "Aabir",
          "Aadam"
        ]
    },
    "Usa":{
       "male":[
          "A_Jay",
          "Aaban",
          "Aabid",
          "Aabir",
          "Aadam"
        ],
       "female":[
          "A_Jay",
          "Aaban",
          "Aabid",
          "Aabir",
          "Aadam"
        ]
    }
}
```

Here is my attempt at reading the json file:

```
//jsonreader.cs

using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class FirstName {
    public List<string> male;
    public List<string> female;
}

public class FirstNames {
    public Dictionary<string, FirstName> countries;
}

public class JSONReader : MonoBehaviour {
    public TextAsset jsonFile;

    void Start(){
        FirstNames firstNamesInJson = JsonUtility.FromJson<FirstNames>(jsonFile.text); 
        Debug.Log("Found name: " + firstNamesInJson.countries["India"].male[0]); 
    } 
}
```

My Debug Log is returning a Null reference error and I'm not sure why.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unity built-in [`JsonUtility`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/JsonUtility.FromJson.html) uses the normal Unity serialization rules .. [`Dictionary` is not supported by it...](https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/script-Serialization.html) the main answer is:

You will need a third-party JSON library in the first place!

Like e.g. `Newtonsoft JSON.Net` (it comes as a [package](https://docs.unity3d.com/Packages/com.unity.nuget.newtonsoft-json@2.0/manual/index.html)) and then as was mentioned before your JSON doesn't have a `root`.

see [Deserialize a Dictionary](https://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/DeserializeDictionary.htm)

```
void Start(){
    var firstNamesInJson = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Dictionary<string, FirstName>>(jsonFile.text); 
    Debug.Log("Found name: " + firstNamesInJson.countries["India"].male[0]); 
}
```

Comment: So thanks to your answer I was able to read the data by changing the JSON and adding an extra step to create my dictionary. Thank you!

Answer (score 3):

Your root json element is a json object which does not have `countries` property so you don't need the "root" object `FirstNames`, use `Dictionary<string, FirstName>` directly:

```cs
var firstNamesInJson = JsonUtility.FromJson<Dictionary<string, FirstName>>(jsonFile.text);
```

P.S.

thanks to [@derHugo](https://stackoverflow.com/users/7111561/derhugo) in the comments - Unity built-in `JsonUtility` does not support the `Dictionary` deserialization ATM ([docs](https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/script-Serialization.html)), so you will need to use 3rd party library for such dynamic deserialization with `Dictionary` (for example [`Newtonsoft.Json`](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Newtonsoft.Json))

Comment: Thank you for that. While it seems to tidy up my code, I'm still not able to return anything  while trying to return this for example; `firstNamesInJson["India"]`

Comment: @camelMilk_ you seem to be confused by the concept of data types. 
I think you can improve your own ability, but simply understanding fully, what return types are, data types in general, classes, variables, interfaces.

I base this purely of the questions you are asking here.

Comment: @MortenBork I know I need to improve my knowledge, that's why I'm here.

Comment: @camelMilk_ Please don't take my comments as hostile, they aren't! 
I am trying to guide you to where you need to improve. 

And the concept of Data types seems to be a current weakness. 

Data types, are basically, the "template" of how the object will be stored in memory, and how much memory needs to be reserved for any data value you wish to store. 

So "List<SomeObject>" is not the same as "SomeObject". List requires way more space.
Same as int vs long or string vs char. etc. 

It is the same for SomeClass vs int, etc.
A compiler can only assign a value to its defined type.

Comment: When you try to claim that <FirstName> is the return type, the parser tries to read the incoming parameter, as that specific type. If you feed it an unknown type, it won't be able to do as it's told. 

Neither can you extract a value from a correctly shaped object, if the return type in your "give me data from this field" index, isn't the same data type as the one you are requesting.

Comment: @MortenBork Ok, so in this instance do I not want to store the arrays of name strings as Lists? I want access to all the names, not just one of them. I tried storing them as `string[]` but it's same result (and I'm sure you understand why and it's clear that I don't).

Comment: Unity built-in `JsonUtility` uses the normal Unity serialization rules .. [`Dictionary` is not supported by it...](https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/script-Serialization.html) the main answer is: You will need a third-party JSON library in the first place

Comment: @derHugo massively helpful information!

Comment: @camelMilk_
I highly recommend, now that you have an answer to your specific problem, that you investigate the cause of your confusion to a fuller extent. This will save yourself a lot of trouble in the future. 

I am not saying this to be patronising. I am saying it because it will help you immensely, to have the knowledge of data types, what they are, how the work, etc. on your backbone, so to speak, when programming. That is all I wanted to communicate.